# Regex any characters except some

Tags: c#, regex

Im trying to create a regex to catch [[xyz|asd]], but not [[xyz]]
In the text:

`'''Diversity Day'''" is the second episode of the [[The Office (U.S. season 1)]|first season]] of the American [[comedy]] [[television program|television series]] ''[[The Office (U.S. TV series)|The Office]]'', and the show's second episode overall. Written by [[B. J. Novak]] and directed by [[Ken Kwapis]], it first aired in the United States on March 29, 2005, on [[NBC]]. The episode guest stars ''Office'' consulting producer [[Larry Wilmore]] as [[List_of_characters_from_The_Office_(US)#Mr._Brown|Mr. Brown]].`

The following results should be captured:

```
[[The Office (U.S. season 1)]|first season]] <-- keep in mind of the "]" before "|", "]" in that case is a literal character not a breaking one "]]"
[[television program|television series]]
[[The Office (U.S. TV series)|The Office]]
[[List_of_characters_from_The_Office_(US)#Mr._Brown|Mr. Brown]]
```

I was trying to use is:

```
\[\[([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\]\]
```

but i cant figure out how to ignore both "|" and "]]" in the groups.
[^|(]])] wont work because it wont match "]]" but only the character "]" (it needs to be the whole word)

Please help, thanks!

Comment: btw, in [[xyz|asd]], should be captured in two groups "xyz" and "asd"

Comment: Please edit your post to format it, it's difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may rely on a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) here:

```
\[\[((?:(?!]]).)*)\|((?:(?!]]).)*)]]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%5C%5B((%3F%3A(%3F!%5D%5D).)*)%5C%7C((%3F%3A(%3F!%5D%5D).)*)%5D%5D&i=%27%27%27Diversity%20Day%27%27%27%22%20is%20the%20second%20episode%20of%20the%20%5B%5BThe%20Office%20(U.S.%20season%201)%5D%7Cfirst%20season%5D%5D%20of%20the%20American%20%5B%5Bcomedy%5D%5D%20%5B%5Btelevision%20program%7Ctelevision%20series%5D%5D%20%27%27%5B%5BThe%20Office%20(U.S.%20TV%20series)%7CThe%20Office%5D%5D%27%27%2C%20and%20the%20show%27s%20second%20episode%20overall.%20Written%20by%20%5B%5BB.%20J.%20Novak%5D%5D%20and%20directed%20by%20%5B%5BKen%20Kwapis%5D%5D%2C%20it%20first%20aired%20in%20the%20United%20States%20on%20March%2029%2C%202005%2C%20on%20%5B%5BNBC%5D%5D.%20The%20episode%20guest%20stars%20%27%27Office%27%27%20consulting%20producer%20%5B%5BLarry%20Wilmore%5D%5D%20as%20%5B%5BList_of_characters_from_The_Office_(US)%23Mr._Brown%7CMr.%20Brown%5D%5D)

**Details**:

- `\[\[` - 2 `[` symbols
- `((?:(?!]]).)*)` - Group 1 (note the `*` can be turned into a lazy `*?` here especially if the first parts are shorter than the second parts) capturing:

  - `(?:(?!]]).)*` - zero or more sequences of

    - `.` - any char (but a newline, use the pattern with `RegexOptions.Singleline` if your strings span across multiple lines)...
    - `(?!]])` - that is not starting a `]]` sequence (i.e. if the `.` does not match a `]` that is followed with another `]`)
- `\|`  - a literal `|`
- `((?:(?!]]).)*)` - Group 2 capturing the same subpattern as Group 2
- `]]` - 2 literal `]` on end.

A much more efficient "unrolled" version of this regex is:

```
\[\[([^]|]*(?:](?!])[^]|]*)*)\|([^]]*(?:](?!])[^]]*)*)]]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%5C%5B(%5B%5E%5D%7C%5D*(%3F%3A%5D(%3F!%5D)%5B%5E%5D%7C%5D*)*)%5C%7C(%5B%5E%5D%5D*(%3F%3A%5D(%3F!%5D)%5B%5E%5D%5D*)*)%5D%5D&i=%27%27%27Diversity%20Day%27%27%27%22%20is%20the%20second%20episode%20of%20the%20%5B%5BThe%20Office%20(U.S.%20season%201)%5D%7Cfirst%20season%5D%5D%20of%20the%20American%20%5B%5Bcomedy%5D%5D%20%5B%5Btelevision%20program%7Ctelevision%20series%5D%5D%20%27%27%5B%5BThe%20Office%20(U.S.%20TV%20series)%7CThe%20Office%5D%5D%27%27%2C%20and%20the%20show%27s%20second%20episode%20overall.%20Written%20by%20%5B%5BB.%20J.%20Novak%5D%5D%20and%20directed%20by%20%5B%5BKen%20Kwapis%5D%5D%2C%20it%20first%20aired%20in%20the%20United%20States%20on%20March%2029%2C%202005%2C%20on%20%5B%5BNBC%5D%5D.%20The%20episode%20guest%20stars%20%27%27Office%27%27%20consulting%20producer%20%5B%5BLarry%20Wilmore%5D%5D%20as%20%5B%5BList_of_characters_from_The_Office_(US)%23Mr._Brown%7CMr.%20Brown%5D%5D&o=x). This regex will treat the first `|` as the inner field separator. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) about how to unroll tempered greedy tokens.

[image]

Comment: WOW! that's exactly what i needed. That was fast! thank you!!

Comment: I do not want to complicate the pattern further, since I think the strings you deal with are not that long. If they are, you may consider unrolling the tempered greedy tokens as described in [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Comment: they're just short strings, so it'll be ok.. thank you very much!

Comment: Even with a short string, this pattern may produce a catastrophic backtracking if the sequence `]]` is not found. The unrolled design is more appropriate here in particular to exclude the pipe in the first part.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Note that it is .NET that is much more efficient than PCRE when it comes to backtracking. When `(?s)a(.*?)z` times out in PHP, the same regex works (just slowly) in .NET. Anyway, an unrolled version is `\[\[([^]]*(?:](?!])[^]]*)*)\|([^]]*(?:](?!])[^]]*)*)]]`, or even `\[\[([^]|]*(?:](?!])[^]|]*)*)\|([^]]*(?:](?!])[^]]*)*)]]` (to just get to the first `|` quicker).